# AddEventListener multiple times performance impact

Tags: javascript, browser

This is my function that adds EventListener.

```
function addEvent(){
   let param1, param2;
   for(let i=0; i< obj.length; i++){
      obj[i].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        doSomething(e, param1, param2)
      }, false();
   }
   //stuff...
}
```

Will it affects performance if obj(nodelist) is quiet large and if I am running this same function multiple time?
If the same EventListener already exists, does it add it again, how to check this?
Would it be better if I were to remove the EventListener before running the function again?
If so, is there a cleaner solution than adding a named function for the callback (for removal)?

Comment: When you pass in a _non-anonymous_ function to `addEventListener` it will not have any issues, but the way you are doing it, it will, because you are calling the method  `doSomething` inside an anonymous method, which means every time you add it you add a call on top of the previous one. Just pass in the `doSomething` method directly. Now, it's best to not continuously add and re-add methods, it's not the fastest process, so avoid it if you can, but otherwise this would work seamlessly.

Comment: passing doSomething directly wouldn't work for me, cuz I have to pass in 2 other parameters to go with it as well.

Comment: Then you will have to be smarter and wrap `doSomething` outside of where you add it. One way would be to use a `WeakMap` to create a link between the passed method and an anonymous method that does the argument thing. Then you can ensure that no method gets duplicated in anonymous methods. **Update**: Actually, no, since both the object and doSomething method are global variables from the code provided, just wrap them in another method (say `function doThing(){ doSomething()` } and add _that_ to your event listener. Problem solved.

Comment: I had the entire code wrap in module pattern, so there's no global code. I guess my main issue was I didn't like the idea to keep adding/removing eventlistener. So, even if I wrap doSomething in doThing(), I still have to pass the param into doThing regardless. If I am understanding this correctly.  Edited the post code a little for better understanding. It's as you said that, there's method inside the anonymous